# MySQL query to get count of unique error codes

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I have a table that looks like this :

```
# ITEM, operating_system, error_code
B01NCUBH43, mac, ['E141202', 'E20012']
B01N4MN9PL, mac, ['E141202', 'E20012']
B06XKH8NXM, win, ['E141202', 'E20012']
B01N3AZUH8, mac, ['E00101', 'E141202']
B06XRRQ8QV, win, ['E00101', 'E141202']
B01NAZ2I1H, mac, ['E00101', 'E141202']
B06XKHJ39Q, mac, ['E141202', 'E20012']
```

I need to find the count of each error code for each operating system. I wrote this sql and it gives me the correct answer. But, it is not a generic and scalable solution as the error_codes are hard coded and there might new error codes in the future.

```
SELECT Platform, 
E141202,
E20012
from
(SELECT
    (CASE WHEN operating_system = 'Win'
        THEN 'Windows'
        WHEN operating_system = 'Mac'
        THEN 'Mac'
    END) Platform,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tag like 'liveItem' THEN ITEM END) total_runs,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN error_code like '%E141202%' THEN ITEM END) E141202,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN error_code like '%E20012%' THEN ITEM END) E20012
FROM CrossPlatformYield where tag = 'liveItem'
GROUP BY Platform)a;
```

Is there any way to get the list of unique error codes and perform the above computation using that this to arrive at the count per error code per operating system ? I would ideally wan't to accomplish it using a MySQL query. In the worst case, I could write a script.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lousy data format.  You should really have a separate table with one row per item and per error.

If you have a fixed number of errors in the list (say up to 2), then I would suggest:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(replace(replace(cpy.error_code, '[', ''), ']', ''), ',', n.n), ',', -1) as error_code,
       operating_system, count(*)
from CrossPlatformYield cpy join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
     on n.n <= length(cpy.error_code) - length(replace(cpy.error_code, ',', '')) + 1
where cpy.tag = 'liveItem'
group by error_code, operating_system;
```

Comment: I'm not getting the right answer with the SQL you provided. Also number of errors might be more. At max 10.